# Doesnt Print Anything While Running Python Script Through Command Line

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is My Simple Code : mycode.py

```
def shara(file):
    import codecs
    import sys
    n=codecs.open(file,'r','utf-8').read()
    print n
    print "mycode"
    raw_input()
```

when i run through command line like this :

```
C:\wamp\PYTHON>python C:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\mycode.py C:\wamp\PYTHON\Scripts\sample.txt
```

it doesnt print anything.

Comment: Are you sure you are seeing it run, try adding `raw_input()` at the end to stop it from exiting

Comment: in the mycode.py file ?

Comment: not working.. it doesnt print anything

Comment: You define a function and never call it. It's not supposed to print anything.

Comment: (aside: Since [file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) is a python builtin, you might want to use a different name in your function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you want python to actually run that function, so you'd need to add:

```
import sys
if __name__ == '__main__':
    shara(sys.argv[1])
```